# Strange repeated discontinuity in nonlinear function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am probably missing something important but here goes:

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x^{t}},\quad1\leq t\leq 2.
$$
When I plot this function and look at very large $x$ it has a strange sawtooth type of behaviour which seems to start around $t=1.8$ and persist until $t=2,$ when it disappears. The general behaviour of this function for large $x$ can be approximated by $$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^{2-t}}\right)$$ which is of course a smooth function and cannot capture this behaviour. Here is a plot  of $f$ for $t=1.9.$

The smooth function has limit $\exp(-1),$ when $t=2,$ and for $t<2,$ it approaches the value $1$ from below as $x \rightarrow \infty.$ The function $f$ also approaches $1$ from below but with this sawtooth behaviour, which I am finding hard to explain.

[image]

For the case $t=1.9,$ at $x\approx 1.344 \times 10^8,$ the last sawtooth ends and the function $f$ approaches $1$ from below smoothly. The red line is the exponential approximation to the function.

Comment: It looks like a computer artifact - this certainly isn't the behavior of the function.

Comment: With numbers that large, I would likewise also initially conclude roundoff errors causing it, but it's amusing nonetheless. It also seems to pop-up quite earlier than you noted as well. ([Demo to play with, for everyone else](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/frkkkewumg))

Comment: What happens when you graph the logarithm of the function, $x^t\log(1-1/x^2)?$ That should show that the function should be strictly increasing. The derivative is $$x^{t-1}\left(t\log(1-1/x^2)+\frac{2}{x^2-1}\right)>\frac{2-t}{x^2-1}$$

Comment: That last inequality because when $0<u<1,$ $$\log(1-u)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u^n}n>-\sum_n u^n =-\frac{u}{1-u}.$$ When $u=1/x^2,$ you get $$\log(1-1/x^2)>-\frac1{x^2-1}.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yes I believe it is an artifact. I plotted the log of the function and still get similar artifacts but your demonstration of monotonicity of the function is fine. Thanks. Feel free to type up as an answer.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha also has this [error](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%281-1%2Fx%5E2%29%5E%28x%5E1.92%29+from+592500+to+593000) except for [this example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%5B%281-1%2Fx%5E2%29%5E%28x%5E1.92%29%2C%7Bx%2C592500%2C593000%7D%5D)

Comment: Yes I also discovered wolfram alpha had it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a floating point calculation artifact. The function is strictly increasing for $x>1.$

If we take: $$g(x)=\log f(x)=x^t\log\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)$$

Then:

$$\begin{align}g'(x)&=tx^{t-1}\log\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)+x^t\dfrac{\frac{2}{x^3}}{1-\frac1{x^2}} \\
&=x^{t-1}\left(t\log\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)+\frac{2}{x^2-1}\right)
\end{align}$$

Then, for $0<u<1,$ $\log(1-u)>-\frac{u}{1-u}.$ So:

$$\log\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)>-\frac1{x^2-1}$$ so:

$$g'(x)> x^{t-1}\frac{2-t}{x^2-1}>0$$ for $x>1.$

So $g$ is a strictly increasing function for $x>1,$ and hence so is $f=e^g.$